# JavaScript date picker doesn't show date

Tags: javascript, spotfire

I'm trying to add a date picker to an html block in Spotfire. Here's my html block:

```
Start Date: <span id="date1"><SpotfireControl id="142f2c81bfc84adc9b97ef30eabb07ec" /></span>
```

I add the following JavaScript:

```
dt1 = document.querySelector("#date1 input").type="date"
```

The result is a date picker for my input, and it works to pick dates, but will only ever show "mm/dd/yyyy" in the input. Any idea how to fix this? I'd like it to show the date I picked.

[image]